# Set up maven plugin connectors in eclipse for "maven-scala-plugin"

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven-2

I'm importing an existing Maven project for Scala. I'm prompted by Eclipse to "Set up maven plugin connectors" for the plugin "maven-scala-plugin" version 2.13.1 but two goals are highlighted red with no optons support available to select.

What plugins are available to support the compile and testCompile goals?

Eclipse is 3.7.2, but I'm not wedded to this version.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to support the compile and testCompile goals, the compilation is done by scala-ide. You need to add the following mess to your pom.xml:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
      <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          <pluginExecutions>
            <pluginExecution>
              <pluginExecutionFilter>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <versionRange>[3.1.0,)</versionRange>
                <goals>
                  <goal>add-source</goal>
                  <goal>compile</goal>
                  <goal>testCompile</goal>
                  <goal>doc</goal>
                  <goal>doc-jar</goal>
                </goals>
              </pluginExecutionFilter>
              <action>
                <ignore />
              </action>
            </pluginExecution>
          </pluginExecutions>
        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

This tells your m2e (the maven plugin for eclipse) to ignore the goals which apply to your `scala-maven-plugin`. You'll have to change the `groupId` & `versionRange` as well.